# Ngb-xx is not a known element

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to use the ngb bootstrap on my Angular project. Every components on ngb throws me an error

[image]

My package.json

[image]

and my app.module.ts

[image]

Did I do something wrong? I followed and read the instructions carefully.

Comment: Please post a working sample that demonstrates your issue. Tried to recreate your issue but it is working for me : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2cfuaf

Answer (score 2):

You have to import into the module you are using for the component , Bootstrap Module as it is mentioned in the [docs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started)

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [NgbModule, ...],
  ...
})
export class YourAppModule {
}
```

It works in this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d9uwjh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-basic.module.ts

Comment: stackblitz link appears broken

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the module is imported into your module in which the component going to use the `Ngb-xx` component. Means if you have a child component which uses Ngb component, include your `Ngb module` not in app module but if you are not using shared module, import it in the app module

With the latest version if `Ngb-bootstrap`, you need to only import the module which you want to use not the whole module like if you need accordian component, you can only import `NgbAccordian` module